# Some questions about Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Why the characteristic of a field is different from two in Lie algebras?

What is the reason for Jacobi's identity in the definition of Lie algebras?

There are Lie algebras of infinite dimension?

Some examples about fields with characteristic two

Thanks for your help

Comment: One does have Lie algebras in characteristic two.

Comment: Jaocbi holds iff $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g}), x \mapsto \text{ad}(x)$ is a morphisms of Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

1.) *Why the characteristic of a field is different from two in Lie algebras?*
The characteristic is arbitrary. However, in characteristic $2$, the skew-symmetry $[x,y]=-[y,x]$ is not enough to conclude that $[v,v]=0$ for all $v$. So the axiom of skew-symmetry is replaced by requiring $[v,v]=0$.

2.) *What is the reason for Jacobi's identity in the definition of Lie algebras?*
The reason is that it comes from the Leibniz rule, differentiating from Lie groups.

3.) *There are Lie algebras of infinite dimension?* Yes, definitely. There are several books on infinite-dimensional Lie algebras, e.g., the book of [Kac](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/infinite-dimensional-lie-algebras/053FE77E6E9B35C56B5AEF7336FE7306).

4.) *Some examples about fields with characteristic two:* Look into a book on abstract algebra, for finite fields of characteristic $2$. For each  power of $2$ there is exactly one such field up to isomorphism.